# Generic base controller in web api

Tags: api, generics, controller

I have the following controllers. All methods of both controllers are same. i want to make a generic base controller and inherit both controllers from this generic base controller. Can anyone please help me.

Course controller

```
 public class CoursesController : ApiController
    {




        CourseRepository repository = new CourseRepository();
        public List<Courseinfo> GetAllCourses()
        {
            var courses = repository.SelectAll();
            var c = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Courseinfo>>(courses);
            return c;

        }
        [ResponseType(typeof(Course))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetCourseById(int id)
        {
            var courses = repository.SelectByID(id);
            if (courses == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var Courseifno = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Courseinfo>(courses);
            return Ok(Courseifno);
        }

        // PUT: api/Courses/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutCourse(int id, Courseinfo courses)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (id != courses.CourseId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            //Student s = new Student();
            var s = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Course>(courses);
            repository.Update(s);
            repository.Save();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

        }

         //POST: api/Courses
        [ResponseType(typeof(Course))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostCourse(Courseinfo course)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


            var Courses = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Course>(course);
            repository.Insert(Courses);

            repository.Save();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = course.CourseId }, course);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Courses/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Course))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteCourse(int id)
        {

            Course Courses = new Course();

            var cour = repository.SelectByID(id);
            if (cour == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            repository.Delete(id);
            repository.Save();

            return Ok(Courses);
        }
```

Student controller

```
public class StudentsController : ApiController
    {




       MystudentRepository repository = new MystudentRepository();
       public IEnumerable<Studentinfo> GetStudents()
       {
           var student = repository.SelectAll();
           var studentinfo = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Studentinfo>>(student);
           return studentinfo;

       }

        [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]

        public IHttpActionResult GetStudents(int id)
        {

            var student = repository.SelectByID(id);
            if (student == null)
            {

               // return NotFound();
                string message = "No student exist";

                throw new HttpResponseException(

                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message));

            }
            var studentifno = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Studentinfo>(student);

            return Ok(studentifno);
        }
        [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutStudent(int id, Studentinfo students)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (id != students.StudentId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            //Student s = new Student();
            var s = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Student>(students);
            repository.Update(s);
            repository.Save();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

        }


        [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostStudent(Studentinfo student)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


            var students = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Student>(student);
            repository.Insert(students);

            repository.Save();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = student.StudentId }, student);
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteStudent(int id)
        {

            Student student = new Student();

            var Std = repository.SelectByID(id);
            if (Std == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            repository.Delete(id);
            repository.Save();

            return Ok(student);
        }
```

1. Please help me that how to make a Generic base controller for these
   two contrllers and then how to inherit each controller for the
   generic base controller.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a generic base controller, cause Attribute routing in Web API doesn't support inheritance of the Route attribute.

As a workaround, you can move controllers logic to separate generic class, add instance to controllers and then call generic class methods inside controllers methods.

For example:

```
public class RepositoryHandler<T> // generic base class that will incapsulate all "controllers generic logic"
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public RepositoryHandler (IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        var data = repository.SelectAll();
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<T>>(data);
    }
}    

public class CoursesController : ApiController
{
    private RepositoryHandler<Courseinfo> _courseHandler;

    public CoursesController()
    {
        IRepository repository = new CourseRepository();
        _courseHandler = new RepositoryHandler<Courseinfo>(repository);
    }

    public List<Courseinfo> GetAllCourses()
    {
        var courseInfo = _courseHandler.GetAll();
        return courseInfo.ToList();

    }
}

public class StudentsController : ApiController
{
    private RepositoryHandler<Studentinfo> _studentHandler;

    public StudentsController()
    {
        IRepository repository = new MyStudentRepository();
        _studentHandler = new RepositoryHandler<Studentinfo>(repository);
    }

    public List<Studentinfo> GetAllStudents()
    {
        var studentinfo = _studentHandler.GetAll();
        return studentinfo.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to do can you help me please?

Comment: But i have a GenericRepositry which i inherited from IGenericRepository

Comment: Sure, you should use your classes/interface. IIRepository was just a name for example